# Equivalent of numpy's newaxis

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors

Numpy has a `newaxis` object that allows you to insert a new dimension of length 1 into an array. So after `y = x[:, numpy.newaxis, :]` we have `y[i, 0, j] == x[i, j]`.
Is there something similar in Mathematica? I'd like something easier to use than `ArrayReshape` that requires knowing the size of the array.

Comment: I don't understand the "length 1" requirement. Please show an example of an `x` and the corresponding `y` you would like to obtain *in Mathematica syntax* rather than as a reference to numpy..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this maybe:

```
NewAxis /: HoldPattern[part : Part[array_, ___, NewAxis, ___]] := 
  With[{i = Rest[List @@ Unevaluated[part]]},
    Part[
      ArrayReshape[array, Fold[Insert[#1, 1, #2] &, Dimensions[array], Position[i, NewAxis]]], 
      Sequence @@ (i /. NewAxis -> All)
    ]
]

x = Array[a, {3, 3}];
y = x[[All, NewAxis]];
y[[All, 1, All]] == x
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's what seems a simple way with `ArrayReshape`, with typical Mathematica syntax. I don't really understand the OP's objection to `ArrayReshape`, and I think that perhaps the flexibility of it was not completely appreciated.

```
ClearAll[insertNewAxis];
insertNewAxis[array_?ArrayQ, level_] := 
 ArrayReshape[array, Insert[Dimensions@array, 1, level]];
```

Examples:

```
array = Table[10 i + j, {i, 3}, {j, 4}]
(*  {{11, 12, 13, 14}, {21, 22, 23, 24}, {31, 32, 33, 34}}  *)

insertNewAxis[array, 2]
% // Dimensions
(*
  {{{11, 12, 13, 14}}, {{21, 22, 23, 24}}, {{31, 32, 33, 34}}}
  {3, 1, 4}
*)

insertNewAxis[array, 1]
% // Dimensions
(*
  {{{11, 12, 13, 14}, {21, 22, 23, 24}, {31, 32, 33, 34}}}
  {1, 3, 4}
*)

insertNewAxis[array, 3]
% // Dimensions
(*
  {{{11}, {12}, {13}, {14}}, {{21}, {22}, {23}, {24}}, {{31}, {32}, {33}, {34}}}
  {3, 4, 1}
*)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll[insertNewDim]
insertNewDim[a_?ArrayQ, l_] := Map[List, a, {l - 1}]
```

Using Michael E2's example `array`:

```
array = {{11, 12, 13, 14}, {21, 22, 23, 24}, {31, 32, 33, 34}};

{#, ## &[#, Dimensions@#] &@insertNewDim[array, #]} & /@ {1, 2, 3} // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant (+1), but I think `Map` will be less efficient when arrays are large and packed (and unpack small ones).

Comment: Thank you @MichaelE2. Great points re efficiency and packing. Now I see